# problem with create array of class object with constructor and then i want to add another value to my object in C++

Tags: c++

problem with create array of class object with constructor and then i want to add another value to my object in C++

I started a class and I want to give it a sixteen startup value and then I can add the teaching knowledge manually.
The program crashes when I want to add a student manually

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student {
    int id;
    string name;
    float letter[5];

public:
    Student(int size) {
        id = size;
        name = "ali";

        for (int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
            letter[i] = 12;
        }
    }

    Student(int size,string Sname, float d[5]) {
        id = size;
        name = Sname;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            letter[i] = d[i];
        }
    }

    void addStd(int size,string Sname) {
        id = size;
        name = Sname;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            letter[i] = 15;
        }
    }

    void PrintStd() {
        cout << id << "\t" << name << "\t";
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
            cout << letter[i] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    Student S1(1);
    float dd1[5] = {20,20,20,20,20};
    Student S2(2,"jack",dd1);

    Student s3[2] = {Student(1),Student(2,"fered",dd1)};

    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        s3[i].PrintStd();
        cout << "*************" << endl;
    }


    Student *s4;

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s4=s3;
    }

    s4[3].addStd(2,"mary");


    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s4[i].PrintStd();
        cout << "************" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

please tell me.
thanks

Comment: I think you're looking for `std::vector`

Comment: Hi  Kerndog73 . It is a university project and the vector is not trained.

Comment: It ought to be taught

Comment: A program that defines a student class and initializes it using the class constructor and can add and search students

Comment: You first need to get you design straight. What is `Student`? It probably should be a _single_ student. But why does it contain `addStd` then? Then you need to learn about arrays. `for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s4=s3;}` just assigns a pointer to another pointer. Then `s4[3]` goes out of bounds, because `s4` points to the same array as `s3`, which has only two elements.

Comment: @user3115252 i have answered your question. Please take a look at it and let me know if it helped you. If it is, then upvote and/or accept. If it is not, provide some feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back). Your main function would then look like the following:

```cpp
int main() {
    float dd1[5] = {20,20,20,20,20};

    std::vector<Student> students;
    students.emplace_back(1);
    students.emplace_back(2,"fered",dd1);

    for (auto& s : students) {
        s.PrintStd();
        cout << "*************" << endl;
    }

    students.emplace_back(2,"mary");

    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    for (auto& s : students) {
        s.PrintStd();
        cout << "*************" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check out [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRAB2TqQAOqBYXVaPUMTQV9/NTobO0cjFzduAE5FZUxVQIYCZmICYONTcyUVSNpM7IJoh2dXDy8FLJy80LqGitsquJqkgEpFVANiZA4AcikAZltkQywAanExnXV64kxmI3nscQAGAEFxyenMOYXl22AN7b3JCdopg1n5nQA3NKJiC93Lg39RGdo1zAKbzMIYzeroeayT67KbMBQKGaZe5aAhzdxQnYzLEzWyovAQsYY7FggjEM5/AGQy7EqisVDMVHsAgEVziACs0jZ7IAIlToTtvAYnKw8MgQNTsUisPQILiwXgAF6YbpoonE7H447c%2BVKvmY9VY/5GI7zbVSSRsPDmvUSg00YgzWX0HFamZbSFWhZcwlWmRyFXidG2g3Ypks94cq1ss1jbWcSR6kNo3m7YmBlN7VOSgjImVy/xKxSk8kMI3K1XB4ma006zCJkNl12lymEy6V7H2x1yvCu92El2PGbe6Q4uT%2BitZpNYsOsyM812cYftrHp4Or/nEqUop2oguYItk37N42kGa0%2BmoiEcrnRgNByfq6ux2v1g2NmvHuuth80khd509jWfYjoBCxDpCo5%2BjId5qlOMwzhG0hRjG2pXkhPKvuq676iu7gZsGTyoJqAAKh6MAQ6AQDBy4zGgBioo8g5Pjog7WmyOgEOaxwsWB74LKxkgJuxnGCZhv7EDuo6xsBno6MOvqyNBE44VOdEMfxYEIey6HRtxAlCRx1rfipaZ4TRal6WBlisJh2GrsZba7HKRjMLYVHKTSdIMjM6DoJw2k3ihqqSFspAhWFoXhSF9kYsG4IgCALyqCQjxbvQGwkrmBAKJh9RZQoAB0mBGN4whDAA%2Bk4IIANYQJw3S5Tm0rZUVJVlZglU1RA5jmlQriYBCgmkL59U2g%2BnYQMw9GoFIABsYIzCAmXNQo1E/tihWkbimSUQ1xlJhZjFgeaABUZ3nRd51cUdOgzNZtlmRuG1NSihXFaVIIdVVyC1T1gkucQACe5p7bFD6HRpt3WZZUPaKwMN3XDCP3Q541/pN01zQtS15Sta0mRtBVbfQO1UWJ2IQzxt2nZdtMnddkOI%2BgNn7didkPisObELQbo2nhwy9KwIDDGywykKYwxbGLqDCyxUEjgo/SDCa1ycGLBDC1L3S9NVIBstwBVjFsAAcWyJGMiSJNw7juKb7izUIwvcGLEtS6QMvDGLCggKFGuSwLpBwLAMCICgqAlXg7BkBQEBoBHUcoMIoiJFsoVUJH4bexATia2LTi2NkgPC2rpBx8a9AAPK0KwRf%2B8NxUiMA7C58NeArOkLze3XmAAB5pPRIxu7iygtyKTjEIXehYMX6tkkYM%2B9DQJMsM3PD8IISdiGOMhCHgTje5AvSoN4JRdwAtOCpoSPLPBe6k6QaBAlhNKYXiWJUsTxGEfgBHQL/fxEQIH9qhuDqPfEoZRGj6HyIIIorwMitGAZ0UBRZyj/xaOUJBX96p9AGEMLggthai3Fi3D2PdjazTPrNbgtFN4zESAVLYjDHS4EIH%2BcYXgZh6Hjq4OYqsVRy0UtIdWudtakF1twNkBVEj2zZJwLYkhZqCUkJItkjthjO1IPPORjDuCSGNvIs2xt3CJEkGyMYDtXbS2Fl7H2pA/Za0DiHCASB%2BgEEFAQcglA47eEjjUN%2B%2BA3iCCXowFeHA14AHcJ7eAXuo4hVj3bCw4TMCJhAEAzHIZQ6htDG70MYYwkR/sxEIFWFgNwVF1GaPntwY20i2SeGNpbLY8YtjuG4NQkhdcPa2N9qInWIBJEFVmokTgKdZqpzZIJUZKj1FjBdqQmx9i%2BnqMkPMrpiyHEC16C8Yg/gNDcCAA%3D%3D%3D)

Some of the problems in your work are that you are trying to add a new student to an existing Student object which logically isn't right at all. Furthermore, your second for loop does not iterate through the whole array (it iterates 2 times but it should be iterating 3 times).

```cpp
int main() {
    float dd1[5] = {20,20,20,20,20};

    Student S1(1);
    Student S2(2,"jack",dd1);

    Student s3[2] = {Student(1),Student(2,"fered",dd1)};

    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
        s3[i].PrintStd();
        cout << "*************" << endl;
    }


    Student s4[3];

    // copying existing elements from s3 to new array s4
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        s4[i]=s3[i];
    }

    // creating 3rd student
    s4[2] = Student(2,"mary");

    cout << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        s4[i].PrintStd();
        cout << "************" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Check out [live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJNJb0AGTy1MAOWMAjTMRABOAAykADqgWE6rR6hiaCfgFqdDZ2jkYubgCsAByKypiqQQwEzMQEIcam5koqUbTZuQQxDs6uHt4KOXkFYZyKTVW2NfF1KQCUiqgGxMgcAORSAMy2yIZYANTikzrqjcSYzEZL2OKeAIJTM3OYi8trtsDbuwf7BgGi87SbmAo%2BzKPzjehLsvvXs8wFAp5tkDFh6IsAOy/PbzOHzWwEBHfSYw%2BGfAjEC6PZ4/a7oqisVDMJHsAgEVziRLSRJUgAieL%2B%2Bx8BicrDwyBA%2BPhoPBBAgfShaPR8Lw6FOdPmnkZsJFcKeRhOS0lUkkbDwqpl3LlNGI8wgiIREqlPw1y1pqI1MjkgvE0O1cvhZIpxCp0g1iRVk0lnEkMsdUIZ%2B3RdqDN1lcN5Wn5hoCAC9MLb7cHHWLjfHMP7HQqld7FpI1ezNajrg6CSR9Ya8MbpZaljoLe65DahWXHc7KdSPV6fX6Sym5aGHUOmRGQQQwdGDRCM%2B0sQ8GDmk8K5WnlZ88Ams3Kc8bF7j%2B%2BGA7rKxDq%2Bva9IjfX5o2Ec2ZH023C7SuA/MO66u/TjZxG8/A2HSEwwdKN6GnJFZ3OBcc1IeZCWJJFvmpWlPWXAC1zzDNtxFXd133RUcPLPUIOvPNLzInRbx%2Be9rUfVsB3fT83W7Y1kKbT0iPhEcxx4h0ADdUDTAAFedGAIdABQYsd0TQAwkXrG9MJ0G9NUSHQCFVU4VOWHFFW01SCypDTizfYjSLNOlLzNBtTQfaR0MYgM5IU5Yb2Y79PQM3S1JMozDwDHjnKGVydKoyxWBwvjgK1UdDSMZhbCk18HQQkl5nQdBODdVCeyFSRvAK0gipK6UYoC7jGLApEGE4CBOCfCrIwnPkQUkCBzFVPh3gAa1VUhMoa2Kx2qz5JjdP0vPXV9qvqgZZs6gsqFcTBvgLAasqfcqYVSisLOVCjz10vsrytWR6JSpz4QUcbPLpAA6UTEWySTGrM%2BEXO8qjVQAKj%2B/6Af%2BrTFN0iKopi0dQJa6NPm4N1boZQ9duICyaxoo6qJO2jzoc6SAwUOG7uVG6WPpcGQNHdECYmn98Oh8DFskBLiAAT1VN7S0pj6Qq%2B%2BYIt5/mQfC7RWAFkXhuI08kSOyVDu0%2BZxtRbGW0umTrsJjiHqe%2BgXoFLi4U%2BoX80kQHTZ%2B4G3NB8WmsArm4XWCdiFoE0keAsYBlYEAxkSMZSFMMZPF91AvZUuirwUIYRiVSRJk4X2CC9wO%2BgGHqQESbh7smTxkk8dxJncdxuEhSEc8hAA2IQve4X3/cD0hg7GX2FBAbwE4D93SDgWAYEQFBUCMHw8HYMgKAgNAB6HuoAVELxvCoIeXWbiAnET32nFsXIWa9uPSHHxV6AAeVoVgt/bgbMAS0R2FXga8HWTJ%2BJeG/MAADwyeTxjrxFlBv9knGITeegsDb3jliIwICBg0B1iwa%2BPB%2BCCGEKIFA9khB4CcM3SAAxUA%2BDKM3MYABaL4yoJBhx4E3dImQNAQEsC0UwbRLDVDiAkcI/hAh0FoSwyIQRGG1DcG0EoGQygVGaPoQoggBGUPKB0HhPQ%2BHtEqBw/h0iuhMLqA1QYwxRhcA9l7H2fsb4NxfskMu%2BCy7cHmNPYA8x3D3U8LY/UuBCAVimG0eYegJ7D3zLHQUoccbx1XsnUgqduCJHuu4cuiROCeEkGXAskgQmJErmMaupBwGRNsdwSQyQom52SJCdwkhEiTArrXIOXsm4t1IG3JOnce4QCQCFFkBByCUHHoPYeghVpOLkVAxgMCOBwIAO4AJ8BApJejSn1y9i4%2BYgzCAIHmEYkxZiLGIKsTYuxddqnuwGAgDYWA3ACiSSk8B3BkhhMSJCTgyQC6eF9J4SE3AzH6LPg3CprcAkpxACE%2B6Zd3CcC8GXTwnhEgFgBfEpJkwa4GPKVUz5STJDQtebC7ZgTH7EACBobgQA%3D%3D%3D)